# Why Arduino reset when I check for serial port using serial.tools.list_ports in python?

Tags: arduino, pyserial

Arduino will reset when DTR signal go Low usually happen when we connect to Serial port.
But when I write code in python using module serial.tools.list_ports. Arduino alway reset when I check for available port except I use Arduino port in other program.
Here my code.

```
def serial_ports():
   return [p.device for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports(include_links=True)]
```

Why I happen and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have correctly mentioned that

> Arduino will reset when the DTR signal goes Low, usually happens when we connect to Serial port.

You might try connecting a 100 Ohm resistor between the 5V pin and the reset pin to stop reset signal going low with the DTR signal.

Comment: Can't do that. I still need to program it via use. Do it has software solution?